# Quais são os comandos/variaveis do batch. Exemplo [%username% ou %groupname%]

Tags: batch, bat

Como obter mais informações das variáveis deste mesmo tipo/modelo?

Existe alguma publicação (link) com mais informações relacionadas a estas variáveis?

Preciso obter o máximo de informações da máquina.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No Windows o comando `SET` já retorna as variáveis de ambiente.

Aqui me retornou:

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\Laércio\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-TVVJ9U4
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Laércio
JD2_HOME=D:\JDownloader
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Laércio\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-TVVJ9U4
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\plugins\
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OneDrive=C:\Users\Laércio\OneDrive
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Laércio\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Laércio\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Laércio\AppData\Roaming\npm
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3d04
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SynaProgDir=Synaptics\SynTP
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\LARCIO~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\LARCIO~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-TVVJ9U4
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-TVVJ9U4
USERNAME=Laércio
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Laércio
windir=C:\Windows
```

Comment: era isso, obg <3

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta conforme a imagem indica: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível, porque da mesma forma que em um código qualquer um pode criar variável, aí mais ainda, então existem ilimitadas variáveis dependendo do que estiver usando. O *batch* é só um algoritmo, ele não tem variáveis pré-definidas, elas existem no seu *script* ou de acordo com os softwares que está usando ali. As variáveis existentes dependem do contexto onde você está.

Fora isto não está no nosso escopo fornecer listas de coisas, apenas aprendizado de conceitos e soluções de problemas específicos, até porque listas são mutáveis.

Você pode usar o comando `set` para listar todas as variáveis que estão disponíveis no momento. Mas nem de longe é a solução que pede a pergunta. É uma ajuda, mas não indica quais variáveis servem para que, que dá o que o AP quer (e só ele sabe exatamente o que quer), ele não diz o que é informação vindo de outras aplicações, o que pode ser enganoso, o que pode ser algo até temerário que está na sua máquina enganando algo. Não considere isto uma solução.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).

Comment: eu queria saber das variaveis padrão do windows, mas não me expressei bem na pergunta, vlw;

Comment: Que Windows? Que versão? Que componentes estão instalados nele? Que outros softwares podem estar interferindo? Acho que não entendeu minha resposta. Não tem como você ter uma lista óbvia.

Answer (score 3):

Como o @maniero comentou, em principio seu batch pode definir as variáveis que quiser.

Porem, o que parece que você quer saber é como ver as variáveis atualmente definidas, e isso é possível.

Inicie um `cmd` e execute o seguinte comando:

```
set
```

Serão mostradas todas as variáveis previamente definidas para seu usuário.

Se você executar

```
set <string>
```

Serão mostradas todas as variáveis iniciadas por `<string>`. Por exemplo,

```
set c
```

Mostrará todas as variáveis iniciadas por "c".

Comment: valeu mano, ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente existem vários comandos que podem retornar diversas informações sobre o computador, o sistema operacional, as variáveis, etc.

> Em bat, podemos usar o [`wmic`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/), [`systeminfo`](https://paulosantanna.com/2012/11/06/systeminfo-comando-poderoso-do-windows-que-muitos-nao-conhecem/), [`reg query`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610537/getting-system-information-using-reg-query) entre outros, como no exemplo abaixo, um bat retirado deste [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1769414-batch-file-to-collect-hardware-info-and-save-to-csv-file)

```bat
@echo off
if %os%==Windows_NT goto WINNT
goto NOCON

:WINNT
echo .Using a Windows NT based system
echo ..%computername%

REM set variables
set system=
set manufacturer=
set model=
set serialnumber=
set osname=
set sp=
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "volume=C:"
set totalMem=
set availableMem=
set usedMem=
set IPv4=
set Domain=

echo Getting data [Computer: %computername%]...
echo Please Wait....

REM Get Computer Name
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic OS Get csname /value') do SET system=%%A

REM Get Computer Manufacturer
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic ComputerSystem Get Manufacturer /value') do SET manufacturer=%%A

REM Get Computer Model
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic ComputerSystem Get Model /value') do SET model=%%A

REM Get Computer Serial Number
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic Bios Get SerialNumber /value') do SET serialnumber=%%A

REM Get Computer OS
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic os get Name /value') do SET osname=%%A
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims='|'" %%A in ("%osname%") do SET osname=%%A

REM Get Computer OS SP
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='='" %%A in ('wmic os get ServicePackMajorVersion /value') do SET sp=%%A

REM Get Memory
FOR /F "tokens=4" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /i "Mem.ria"') do if defined totalMem (set availableMem=%%a) else (set totalMem=%%a)
set totalMem=%totalMem:,=%
set availableMem=%availableMem:,=%
set /a usedMem=totalMem-availableMem

FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i IN ('fsutil volume diskfree %volume%') DO (
    SET "diskfree=!disktotal!"
    SET "disktotal=!diskavail!"
    SET "diskavail=%%j"
)
FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%i IN ("%disktotal% %diskavail%") DO SET "disktotal=%%i"& SET "diskavail=%%j"

( 
>nul echo/%processor_architecture% | findstr /l "...64" && set "processor_architecture_plataform=AMD64"
) || (
set "processor_architecture_plataform=%processor_architecture%
)

echo done!

echo --------------------------------------------
echo System Name: %system%
echo Manufacturer: %manufacturer%
echo Model: %model%
echo Serial Number: %serialnumber%
echo Operating System: %osname%
echo C:\ Total: %disktotal:~0,-9% GB
echo C:\ Avail: %diskavail:~0,-9% GB
echo Total Memory: %totalMem%
echo Used  Memory: %usedMem%
echo Computer Processor: %processor_architecture_plataform% 
echo Service Pack: %sp%
echo --------------------------------------------

REM Generate file
SET file="%~dp0%computername%.txt"
echo -------------------------------------------- >> %file%
echo Details For: %system% >> %file%
echo Manufacturer: %manufacturer% >> %file%
echo Model: %model% >> %file%
echo Serial Number: %serialnumber% >> %file%
echo Operating System: %osname% >> %file%
echo C:\ Total: %disktotal:~0,-9% GB >> %file%
echo C:\ Avail: %diskavail:~0,-9% GB >> %file%
echo Total Memory: %totalMem% >> %file%
echo Used  Memory: %usedMem% >> %file%
echo Computer Processor: %processor_architecture% >> %file%
echo Service Pack: %sp% >> %file%
echo -------------------------------------------- >> %file%

echo %system%, %model%, %serialnumber%, %osname%, > hardware-audit.csv
REM systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name" /c:"OS Name" /c:"OS Version" /c:"System Manufacturer" /c:"System Model" /c:"System type" /c:"Total Physical Memory" /c:"Domain"

REM request user to push any key to continue
pause

goto END

:NOCON
echo Error...Invalid Operating System...
echo Error...No actions were made...
goto END

:END
```